# Child theme Customization with Custom action on separated file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I am now developing Woocommerce Child theme.
I want to add my custom action to woocommerce_single_product_summary.

like this .

```
<?php
            function show_stock() {
              global $product;
              echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
            }
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            //remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',20);
            // add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',7);
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','show_stock',7);
            do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
```

here you can see I added code to content-single-product.php but I want to add show_stock.php like others such as short-description.php ...

Looking forward your help.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand the question. But when you store code in a separate file you need to tell WordPress at some point that the file exists. So use "include" or "require" somewhere, maybe in a "loader.php" or your "functions.php", to load your show_stock.php

Answer (score 0):

In your `functions.php` you would add:

```
function show_stock() {
    global $product;
    echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','show_stock',7);
```